# How do you do terrain deformation/destruction?

Tags: python, pygame, pymunk

I'm messing around with pymunk and I'm trying to get destructible terrain.
I have 2 bodies (one is kinematic and the other dynamic).
The kinematic body has a single large box shape while the other has several shapes with a large pertrusion that is set as a "sensor" so it could overlap with other shapes (this is my "excavator").
they are both added to a collision handler and successfully trigger a collision. My `begin` handler looks like this:

```
def handle(arbiter, space, data):
    radius = arbiter.shapes[1].radius
    space.remove(arbiter.shapes[1])
    platform = Polygon([arbiter.shapes[1].body.local_to_world(vertex) for vertex in arbiter.shapes[1].get_vertices()])
    car = Polygon([arbiter.shapes[0].body.local_to_world(vertex) for vertex in arbiter.shapes[0].get_vertices()])
    vects = [vect for vect in (platform.difference(car)).exterior.coords]
    new_shape = pm.Poly(arbiter.shapes[1].body, vects, radius=radius)
    new_shape.friction = arbiter.shapes[1].friction
    new_shape.elasticity = arbiter.shapes[1].elasticity
    new_shape.collision_type = arbiter.shapes[1].collision_type
    space.add(new_shape)
    return True
```

Where `pm` is `pymunk` and `Polygon` is `shapely.geometry.Polygon`
I've attempted to use shapely as it allows to get the difference between polygons.

Unfortunately all that I see happening is flickering as the new boxes are drawn. Is this the wrong approach?

EDIT: After some further testing, this seems to kinda work when I'm impacting vertices, but not edges. I am unsure on how to proceed

EDIT 2: Here is a  minimal program to demonstrate the problem (controls with WASD and Q,E for rotation)

```
import pymunk as pm
from pymunk import pygame_util
import pygame as pg
from pymunk import autogeometry
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, MultiPolygon

pygame_util.positive_y_is_up = False


def make_rect(position=(100, 400), dims=(30, 10), btype=pm.Body.DYNAMIC):
    body = pm.Body(body_type=btype)
    body.position = position
    shape = pm.Poly.create_box(body, dims, 2)
    shape.friction = 1
    shape.mass = 100
    shape.elasticity = 0.2
    print(f'Rect --- r={2}, pos={position}, type:{btype}, mass:{body.mass}, moment:{body.moment}')
    return body, shape


def handle(arbiter, space, data):
    vects = []
    radius = arbiter.shapes[0].radius
    platform = Polygon([arbiter.shapes[0].body.local_to_world(vertex) for vertex in arbiter.shapes[0].get_vertices()])
    digger = Polygon([arbiter.shapes[1].body.local_to_world(vertex) for vertex in arbiter.shapes[1].get_vertices()])
    diff = platform.difference(digger)
    if type(diff) is MultiPolygon:
        polies = [polygon for polygon in platform.difference(digger)]
        print('multi!')
    else:
        polies = [diff]
    for polygon in polies:
        vects = autogeometry.simplify_curves([vect for vect in polygon.exterior.coords], 30)
        new_shape = pm.Poly(arbiter.shapes[0].body, vects, radius=radius)
        new_shape.friction = arbiter.shapes[0].friction
        new_shape.elasticity = arbiter.shapes[0].elasticity
        new_shape.collision_type = arbiter.shapes[0].collision_type
        space.remove(arbiter.shapes[0])
        if new_shape.area > 500:
            space.add(new_shape)
        else:
            del new_shape
    print(vects)
    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    screen = pg.display.set_mode([800, 800])
    space = pm.Space()
    space.gravity = (0, 0)

    dirt = make_rect((300, 300), (100, 75), pm.Body.KINEMATIC)
    dirt_body = pm.Body(body_type=pm.Body.KINEMATIC)
    dirt = pm.shapes.Poly(dirt_body, [(300, 300), (600, 300), (600, 500), (300,500)], radius=1)
    dirt.collision_type = 1
    car_body = make_rect((100, 300), (70, 30))
    digger = pm.Poly(car_body[0], [(+70, 20), (+70, -20), (-10, 0)], radius=1)
    digger.collision_type = 2
    digger.mass = 0
    digger.sensor = True

    space.add(*car_body, dirt, dirt_body, digger)

    handler = space.add_collision_handler(1, 2)
    handler.begin = handle
    options = pm.pygame_util.DrawOptions(screen)
    options.constraint_color = (10, 20, 30, 40)
    options.flags = pm.SpaceDebugDrawOptions.DRAW_SHAPES
    options.flags |= pm.SpaceDebugDrawOptions.DRAW_COLLISION_POINTS
    options.flags |= pm.SpaceDebugDrawOptions.DRAW_CONSTRAINTS
    font = pg.font.SysFont("Consolas", 24)
    clock.tick(60)

    running = True
    while running:
        screen.fill((200, 200, 200))
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                running = False

        key = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pg.K_a]:
            car_body[0].apply_impulse_at_local_point((0, -100), car_body[0].center_of_gravity)
        if key[pg.K_d]:
            car_body[0].apply_impulse_at_local_point((0, 100), car_body[0].center_of_gravity)
        if key[pg.K_w]:
            car_body[0].apply_impulse_at_local_point((100, 0), car_body[0].center_of_gravity)
        if key[pg.K_s]:
            car_body[0].apply_impulse_at_local_point((-100, 0), car_body[0].center_of_gravity)
        if key[pg.K_q]:
            car_body[0].apply_impulse_at_local_point((0, 50), car_body[0].center_of_gravity - pg.Vector2(35, 0))
            car_body[0].apply_impulse_at_local_point((0, -50), car_body[0].center_of_gravity + pg.Vector2(35, 0))
        if key[pg.K_e]:
            car_body[0].apply_impulse_at_local_point((0, 50), car_body[0].center_of_gravity + pg.Vector2(35, 0))
            car_body[0].apply_impulse_at_local_point((0, -50), car_body[0].center_of_gravity - pg.Vector2(35, 0))
        if key[pg.K_SPACE]:
            pass


        space.debug_draw(options)
        screen.blit(
            font.render("fps: " + str(clock.get_fps()), True, pg.Color("white")),
            (0, 0),
        )
        pg.display.flip()
        fps = clock.get_fps() or 60
        dt = 1.0 / fps
        space.step(dt)
        clock.tick(60)
    pg.quit()
```

Comment: I dont see any obvious problem, but at the same time Ive never used shapely.. Anyway, i think your best way forward is to make the problem easier to debug first, and experiment with just this feature. For example, if you make a car and a platform, and collide them with shapely will the resulting shape look correct if you just print it out (or draw to screen?).

Comment: @viblo this is what I'm doing. I have a triangle "drill" impacting a rectangle "dirt". after a lot of testing it appears to work if any of the vertices in the rectangle are inside the triangle, but does appear to work otherwise. Are you familiar with a better way to calculate polygon overlap?

Comment: Maybe you can make a minimal example that shows the problem (and is possible to experiment with)?

Comment: @viblo I added a full example. if you collide your triangle with a corner of the large box it will deform, but wont otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

With your full example I understand the issue. Poly shapes in Pymunk are convex. If you try and create a Poly shape that is not, a convex hull around the vertices will be automatically created. I think this is why you can only dig at the vertices.

To fix this, I think you can take the Polygon that you get from shapely, and then split it up into convex polygons. Either you use something from shapely, just looking quickly I found there's a triangulate function that would work (triangles are always convex). Or you can use the convex decomposition method in Pymunk: http://www.pymunk.org/en/latest/pymunk.autogeometry.html#pymunk.autogeometry.convex_decomposition

From both of these methods you will get several polygons out, meaning that after a little bit of digging the original rectangle Poly shape will instead become several smaller Poly shapes. You can attach many shapes to a single body, so from Pymunks side there's no problem.